# How to create a common class for alertDialog Box

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

How to create a class for `alertDialogBox`, and it should be called for every `Activity`.  I used a close button on every `Activity` while pressing the close Button, The Alert Box should kill all activities in my application.

Comment: u just want a commom alert box for all activities? or make that alertbox to kill all the activities in your application ?

Comment: want to make that alertbox to kill the all activities in my application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a class like **CustomDialog.class**,

and inside of it create a static method like the one below,

```
 public static void ExitAppDialog(final Activity activity)
 {
     AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
     alertbox.setTitle("Warning");
     alertbox.setMessage("Exit Application?");
     alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes", new
     DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
         activity.finish();
     }
     });
     alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new
     DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

     }
     });
     alertbox.show();
 }
```

And in your activity's onBackPressed() call this method like this,

```
public void onBackPressed()
{
    CustomDialog.ExitAppDialog(myActivity.this );
}
```

Comment: @Thamilvanan: One more suggestion, Create an `Activity`(say `BasicActivity`) and override `onBackPressed()` like @AndroSelva said, and extend every `Activity` from your `BasicActivity`

Comment: Another way is another apporach is that Create an Activity(say ImplementedActivity) and override onBackPressed() like @AndroSelva said and in other activities instead of extending Activity you can extend ImplementedActivity eg ClassB extends ImplementedActivity

Comment: guys am getting the dialogbox.its come fine.but i have one more doubt.in my application i used exit button in all activity .while clicking that exit button .i need to close the main Activity like start (initial) Activity.how can i do that.i cant understand.

Comment: you have to try what Adil Soomro has suggested here in the comment. It might be handy in your case.